# Umbraco backend translation

Tags: xml, umbraco

I'm new in Umbraco.
I was translate umbraco backend to persian with xml file and placed it in Umbraco/Config/Lang
everything's right except that some words are not Available in XML file.      I mean there's no key string in XML file for some words.
How should i translate them?

[image: umbraco]

Answer (score 2):

For translating tabs you should be looking at `Dashboard.config` located under Config folder. You should be editing the caption attribute directly because umbraco does not use translation service for the dashboard. Take a look at the example xml:

```
<section alias="StartupDeveloperDashboardSection">
    <areas>
      <area>developer</area>
    </areas>
    <tab caption="Get Started">  
      <control showOnce="true" addPanel="true" panelCaption="">
        views/dashboard/developer/developerdashboardvideos.html
      </control>
    </tab>
    <tab caption="Examine Management">
      <control>
        views/dashboard/developer/examinemanagement.html
      </control>
    </tab>
</section>
```

The left menu under developer section (Data Types, Macros, Packages,...) and all the other sections is defined under `trees.config` file.

```
<trees>
   <!--Content-->
   <add initialize="true" 
        sortOrder="0" 
        alias="content" 
        application="content" 
        title="Content" iconClosed="icon-folder" 
        iconOpen="icon-folder" 
        type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.ContentTreeController, umbraco" />
   ...
</trees>
```

Take a look at the `alias` attribute, it is used as the key in language translation xml. So if it is not in the xml just add it there and you should be good.

```
<key alias="content">Content translated</key>
```